# how to implement same action for textview and button?

Tags: java, android, handler

I want to have same thing happen when I press a button as I press enter on text edit(**s**).

Here is implementation of `OnEditorActionListener` for text edit:

```
 private OnEditorActionListener clickedEnter = (new OnEditorActionListener()
 {
  @Override
  public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
      //implemtation of task1
      }
      return false;
  }
 });
```

And here is implementation for the button:

```
show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
          //How can I call clickedEnter here?
        }
    });
```

The reason is, I want to have less code and easier debugging etc. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a function with the "task1" you want to perform and invoke from both listeners. Simple!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:

```
    final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    editText.setOnEditorActionListener(clickedEnter);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editText.onEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
        }
    });
```

And here's my xml:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dp "
    android:text="Done!"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textColor="#333"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:hint="Enter text"/>
```

Depends on what [action](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo.html) you want to invoke within the editor.

Comment: I need to invoke clickedEnter. I am not really sure which one I need to change!

Comment: @Bernard so what's wrong with my solution? It's clean and it works.

Comment: I get error that I must define textView variable. Can you explain a bit that in my example which variable should be replaced?

Comment: I really appreciate your time. But I have plural number of EditText so listener for final must be a private method. Could you please implement it in the situation when I have a the following as function:  private OnEditorActionListener clickedEnter = (new OnEditorActionListener()

Comment: @Bernard I'm not sure if I understood correctly but see the updated answer. You can set what ever listener you want. Just need to keep the same `EditText`.

Answer (score 1):

You can either create a method and call it in the two functions, or call show.performClick() in the first method.

Solution 1:

```
private OnEditorActionListener clickedEnter = (new OnEditorActionListener()
{
  @Override
  public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
      yourMethod();
      }
      return false;
  }
});  

show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
          yourMethod();
        }
 }); 

private void yourMethod(){
      //Instructions
}
```

Solution 2 :

```
private Button show;

private OnEditorActionListener clickedEnter = (new OnEditorActionListener()
{
  @Override
  public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
      show.performClick();
      }
      return false;
  }
});  

show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
          //Instructions...
        }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but How can I call clickedEnter in the second one?

Comment: Thanks again but in your second solution, I need to have Instructions in the first one and in the second one I call first one.

Comment: performClick() only works for View, so you won't be able to call this function in the second listener. However, if you use the second solution, it should be still working, because you will have the same instructions executed. If this doesn't work, you can still use the first solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a different method for your task and call that method in both the listener's events.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this

```
etOne.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                        KeyEvent event) {
                    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                        bSearch.performClick();
                        closeKeyboard(getActivity(),
                                etOne.getWindowToken());
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

and

```
bSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            //Do something..

            }
        });
```

now the button will //Do something .. and if you want that when user press enter on keyboard and the same thing happens as what the button does.. just call `bSearch.performClick();` hope it helps..

Edit : also `closeKeyboard(getActivity(),etOne.getWindowToken());` will auto hide the soft keyboard after hitting enter.

Comment: I know very basic but as I said in question there plural of text edits so I have a private function as listener. And also I want to call that private function inside the second one which is bSearch in your example. Instead of //Do something I want to call a function which is listener for couple of edit text.